# Are there any known results for the spectrum of $(-\Delta)^s/V^{p-1}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, laplacian, fractional-calculus

I am interested in generalizing some results known for the $\frac{-\Delta}{U^{p-1}}$ where $U$ is a Talenti bubble to the non-local operator $\frac{(-\Delta)^s}{V^{p-1}}$ where $U$ and $V$ are bubbles with appropriate powers and parameters $\mu\in \mathbb{R}, \xi\in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$U(x)=\alpha\left(\frac{\mu}{\mu^{2}+|x-\xi|^{2}}\right)^{\frac{N-2}{2}}, \quad \alpha>0$$
$$V(x)=\alpha\left(\frac{\mu}{\mu^{2}+|x-\xi|^{2}}\right)^{\frac{N-2 s}{2}}, \quad \alpha>0.$$

There is a discussion about $-\Delta/U^{p-1}$ in the Appendix of this [paper by Bianchi and Egnell](http://web.math.unifi.it/users/bianchi/lavori/bianchi_egnell_sobolev.pdf), however, I have not come across any discussion on the spectral properties involving the fractional laplacian.

In particular, we can see that $1,p$ are the eigenvalues of both $-Delta/U^{p-1}$ and $(-\Delta)^s/V^{p-1}$, however since we can't use Sturm-Livouille theory for the fractional Laplacian operator it is not clear whether the second eigenvalue is indeed equal to $p.$

Any references/ideas will be much appreciated.

PS. Here $s\in (0,1)$ and $p=2^{*}-1=\frac{n+2}{n-2}$ or $p=\frac{n+2s}{n-2s}$ for the fractional laplacian case.

Comment: Not sure about your question, but you can have a look at Davila, del Pino, Sire in Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 141 (2013), 3865--3870.

Comment: @GabS I looked at it before and their main result is that if a bounded function annihilates the operator $(-\Delta)^s/V^{p-1}$ then it is a linear combination of the derivatives of $V$. But it still does not give us much information about the spectrum